# Run js when pop over text input is loaded

Tags: javascript, popover, cleave

Wanted to have cleave.js to format text input on the fly.

I have 2 text inputs

1. HTML text input and
2. also a pop over text input whenever search icon is clicked.

The issue is on popover text input where cleave text formating is not 
    working.

I believe it could be related to the element hasn't exist somehow? I have try to listen to listener but no luck so far.  .on('shown.bs.popover)

My code as as per below
https://jsfiddle.net/fairul82/y3kf92oq/
Libraries used : cleave,js , bootstrap popover , jquery

```
 HTML
<div class="container">
 <h3>Bootstrap 3 Popover HTML Example</h3>
 <input type="text" class="input-element"><br>
 <ul class="list-unstyled">
 <li><a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data- 
container="body" data-placement="left" type="button" data-html="true" 
href="#" id="login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="margin:3px 0 0 0"></span></a></li>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
  <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h1>
        My Content
      </h1>
      <input type="text" class="input-element"><br>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
//JS
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
 html: true,
 content: function() {
 return $('#popover-content').html();
 }
 });

 $("[data-toggle=popover]").on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
 // alert('called back');
 const cleave = new Cleave('.input-element', {
 numeral: true,
   numeralThousandsGroupStyle: 'thousand'
 });
 });

 const cleave = new Cleave('.input-element', {
 numeral: true,
  numeralThousandsGroupStyle: 'thousand'
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution https://jsfiddle.net/ztkv8w60/19/

According to authority document https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js, it has a note `.input-element here is a unique DOM element. If you want to apply Cleave for multiple elements, you need to give different css selectors and apply to each of them`.

It is tricky question, because the `bootstrap popover` creates the same element as your specific div when the icon gets a click. Therefore there are two the same element,  you have to point it out which element is in a popover.

Comment: Thanks! Any reason why css selector < .popover .input-element-2  >  works but not  < .input-element-2> selector

Comment: @FRizal No problem. There are two element have class `.input-element-2` when you click the search icon,  it is beacuse `bootstrap popover` creates other one.  So here I point the specific element out, that element is a div has `popover` class, this is what `bootstrap popover` created,  that's it. Have a good day.